# What does "ni sou" mean in ごく自然にそうなる

Tags: translation, parsing, grammar

When I Google translate the sentence it says "it will happen very naturally".

If I break down the sentence into parts:

Goku: very (adverb)

Shizen: naturally (adverb)

Ni sou: ???

Naru: to become

Can someone help explain what the "ni sou" part means?

Comment: You’re splitting it wrong. 自然に + (そう + なる)

Comment: thank you for clearing the confusion. Since sou is a NA adjective it just simply combined with naru as well after flipping back a few chapters in my genki textbook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

自然に is the adverb form of 自然. When に is attached to the end of な-adjs, they are converted into adverbs. Similarly, when い is replaced with く in い-adjs, they also become adverbs.

自然→自然に 
優しい→優しく

そう＋なる = become like that

> 自然にそうなる 
> Become like that naturally.

Also, Google translate is not very useful when it comes to learning Japanese. Maybe try pasting the sentence into a dictionary like [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%94%E3%81%8F%E8%87%AA%E7%84%B6%E3%81%AB%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B) instead.

Comment: ohh, and im guessing "そう" is referring to https://www.nihongomaster.com/dictionary/entry/601/sou

Comment: That's correct :)

Comment: thank you so much for explaining!